# How can I receive access token from LinkedIn

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

How could I receive the oauth2_access_token from LinkedIn using requests-oauthlib library in python having username and password? Or I need to create an application? And what if I want to receive tokens for different users? Thank you.

Comment: Did you check out https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib/blob/master/docs/examples/linkedin.rst (the 1st in Google on "linkedin access token requests-oauthlib")?

Comment: that what I am saying this way I get the token only for a specific account, but what if I need token to access profile or post something from another account, I need to register another client_id client_secret.

Comment: AFAICS, you rather need client_id per _application_, not per user. You enter the user's login and password in the browser at `authorization_url`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem using (selenium, oauthlib, PyLinkedinAPI).
It works as follows:
1. request for authorization link using oauthlib
2. enter email and password using selenium
3. get token from redirect URL using oauthlib
4. post on LinkedIn using PyLinkedinAPI and token for the specific user

this way I can loop through account credentials and get required token.
Thanks for everybody suggestions.